# Vote to close a question automatically upvotes comment that disagrees

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, vote-to-close

So the following happened:

1. A question was closed as a duplicate of question X
2. Someone disagreed and reopened the question, adding a comment explaining why themselves. In that comment, they linked to the duplicate target X.
3. I disagreed with the arguments and re-closed the question as a duplicate of X.

Now, since I closed the question and that comment contained a link to the duplicate target, the system assumed that the comment was a *“I think this is a duplicate of X”* comment and automatically upvoted the comment on my behalf. But my action of re-closing the question actually means the complete opposite.

So now the comment is upvoted (by myself) making it appear to others that someone else agreed with the reopening although that might not necessarily be the case.

Could the auto-upvoter be adjusted to not be as greedy with the comment detection?

Comment: Any suggestions? I don't see an obvious way to make the auto-upvoter smart enough to support this.

Comment: I don't get the course of events here. Seems the target is always X... Could you give letters to question being closed and dupe target ? maybe with D1 and T1,T2 to clear it up ?

Comment: Well, it could be made stricter to only check very specific comment patterns, since most of the time, these comments are automatically created from flags. Or for this specific situation, check if the comment author reopened the question before. – In doubt, there should rather not be an upvote instead of an incorrect upvote which you cannot undo.

Comment: @Tensibai It’s always the same dupe target X. In step 2, the question was simply reopened with a comment linking to that target X explaining why they believe the question is not a duplicate. Afterwards in step 3, the question was re-closed as a duplicate of the same X as in step 1.

Comment: Ok, found it, good luck fighting with Wiktor, FGITW for regexes

Comment: I wonder if the upvote comes from the system or someone else agreeing with the comment author. I assume only SO devs can answer the question.

Comment: @Tensibai I can see that the comment upvote is supposedly mine. It even says “you've voted for this as a useful comment” when I hover over it, just like with normal upvotes.

Comment: Ok, so it comes from the close vote. I'm unsure this worth fixing, sometimes I link to posts I found as Related when I'm not sure this would answer the question, and someone with more knowledge use the link as dupe target. Always though it was a manual upvote on the comment...

Comment: Alternatively, this could be a feature request to be able to un-upvote comments :P

Comment: @poke You can do that, [but there are some limitations](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129032/167646).

Comment: Note that fixing [this bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141414/dont-delete-comments-with-link-to-duplicate-if-they-are-modified) should also fix this one. It's high time that got done.

Comment: Agreed, the system is too eager to create a linkage of some kind between dupe target and comments that *might* be related. Some more elegant logic is called for, I think.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this. The code that handled the automatic upvote for duplicate comments was outdated and indeed performing a text search of the original post Id in all of the previous comments. We have created a stricter check so that auto upvotes are cast when the comment is actually a duplicate of another, rather than when the duplicate question Id appears in the text body of a previous comment.

Comment: "The comment is actually a duplicate of another [comment?]". I don't understand, when does that happen?

Comment: If you vote to close a question as a duplicate, it leaves a comment. If someone else votes to close as a duplicate, it would leave another comment. It does not leave another comment if an exact duplicate comment already exists. @Oriol

Comment: But the issue I mentioned is not really related to *leaving* comments. Or does it mean that the new behavior is that only automatically created duplicate question comments ever get upvoted automatically?

Comment: Only automatically created duplicate question comments will get upvoted automatically.